# How to add help-text above input rather than below it in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

In creating forms using Twitter Bootstrap, how do you add help text *above* the input rather than below it. When I insert a statement above the input using the "help-block" class, the label and the input no longer align. Is there a way around that?

Answer (score 19):

The bootstrap already have this kind of resource on it's css class. Take a look on the [samples](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/).

Your code must be on a `form-group` class, like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="info-email" class="col-xs-2 control-label">e-mail</label>
   <div class="col-xs-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="info-email" placeholder="Your e-mail">
      <small class="text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
   </div>
</div>
```

[image: sample of below]

And, if you need to put the help text above the input, just change the place of the `<small>...</small>` to the above of the input:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="info-email" class="col-xs-2 control-label">e-mail</label>
   <div class="col-xs-10">
      <small class="text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="info-email" placeholder="Your e-mail">
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: sample of above]

Answer (score 8):

Prepend help-block class element to controls

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label for="prependedInput" class="control-label">Prepended text</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <p class="help-block">Here's some help text</p>
        <div class="input-prepend">
           <input type="text" class="span2" id="prependedInput" size="16">
        </div>
   </div>
```

Instead of appending

```
 <div class="control-group">
    <label for="prependedInput" class="control-label">Prepended text</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <div class="input-prepend">
           <input type="text" class="span2" id="prependedInput" size="16">
        </div>
        <p class="help-block">Here's some help text</p>
   </div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/935/

Comment: I'm looking for the label ("Prepended Text") and the input field to be aligned, with the help text ("Here's some help text") simply above the input field. I've figured out a way to do it with an extra, separate div but I was curious if there was a way to do it more simply with Bootstrap